# C/C++: Inherent ambiguity of "\xNNN" format in literal strings

Tags: c++, c, string, hex, literals

Consider these two strings:

```
wchar_t* x = L"xy\x588xla";
wchar_t* y = L"xy\x588bla";
```

Upon reading this you would expect that both string literals are the same except one character - an `'x'` instead of a `'b'`.
It turns out that this is not the case. The first string compiles to:

```
y = {'x', 'y', 0x588,  'x', 'l', 'a' }
```

and the second is actually:

```
x = {'x', 'y', 0x588b, 'l', 'a' }
```

They are not even the same length!
Yes, the `'b'` is eaten up by the hex representation (`'\xNNN'`) character.

At the very least, this could cause confusion and subtle bugs for in hand-written strings (you could argue that unicode strings don't belong in the code body)

But the more serious problem, and the one I am facing, is in auto-generated code. There just doesn't seem to be any way to express this: `{'x', 'y', 0x588,  'b', 'l', 'a' }` as a literal string without resorting to writing the entire string in hex representation, which is wasteful and unreadable.

Any idea of a way around this?
What's the sense in the language behaving like this?

Comment: Ouch, just ran into this in C. Luckily the VS2013 compiler warned me that my hex character value was outside the 'char' range.

Answer (score 14):

A simple way is to use compile time string literal concatenation, thus:

```
wchar_t const* y = L"xy\x588" L"bla";
```